# Multiplication and Output not working in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16, fasm

I've been trying to get the square of a number inputted by the user, but whenever I change my value from 2 to 3, my dosbox freezes and I am not able to know what's incorrect.

```
org 100h

mov ah,40h;read
mov bx,1
mov cx,8
mov dx, msg
int 21h

mov ah, 3fh
mov bx, 0
mov cx, 1
mov dx,num
int 21h


mov al, 5
mov bl, 3
mul bl
AAM
mov ch, ah
mov cl, al

mov dl, ch
add dl, 48
mov ah, 3
int 21h

mov dl, cl
add dl, 48
mov ah, 3
int 21h


mov ah, 4ch
int 21h


num rb 1
msg db "Number: "
```

I'm using FASM, and that is the only assembler I am allowed to.
Right Now the program should display the multiplication of 5 by 3 but that doesn't work either.

Comment: You might want to use an emulator that has a debugger which you could use to single-step your program and find the problem.

Comment: The display character is `ah=2` not `ah=3` which is "wait for AUX input". You were changing the wrong values.

Comment: @Jester It worked, but now I have another question? Why is AAM necessary for the multiplication to work?

Comment: @AndrejHatzi: It's because you want a result in binary-coded decimal rather than binary, to save you the trouble of converting from binary to decimal before outputting.  You can [read](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/aam) the full details of what the instruction does.

Comment: Why when I change 5 and 3 to the variable [num] it stops working and doesn't show it's multiplication?

Comment: You did it wrong. But we can't guess how unless you show code.

Comment: `mov al, [num]
mov bl, [num]
mul bl
AAM
mov ch, ah
mov cl, al`

Comment: Note that user input is [ascii code](http://www.asciitable.com), you need to convert it. The multiplication itself should be fine.